# Updating panel contents in a Firefox extension

Tags: firefox-addon, content-script

I'm trying to go by the suggestion in https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/panel of using a contentScript to update the contents in my panel. Currently, I have a server that returns the html that I want to display in my panel. I do `panel.postMessage("update_panel", contents);` when I have the response ready, and have a contentScriptFile associated with the panel that contains

```
self.port.on("update_panel", handleMessage);

function handleMessage(message) {
    document.write(message);
}
```

However, I don't see anything being updated, and I'm also unable to debug the contentScriptFile (is there an way to do so?).

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up figuring something out.

```
panel.port.on("updating_done", function(response) {
    console.log(response);
});

panel.port.emit("update_panel", contents);
```

If anyone can explain why this works and postMessage doesn't, that would be great.